# Get records from AX with pagination [AX 2009]

Tags: c#, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

I am trying to get a certain number of records at a time from AX. 
I want to perform something equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() AS ROWNO
FROM TableName) 
    AS TableName WHERE ROWNO > startIndex 
AND ROWNO <= endIndex;
```

Currently, I am fetching all records from AX (using .net business connector) :

```
axRecord.ExecuteStmt("select * from %1");
i = 0;
while(axRecord.Found)
{
 if(i<startIndex)
 {
  i++;
  continue;
 }
 // Perform operations
 i++;
 if(i==endIndex)
 {
   break;
 }
}
```

Is there is a better way to do this using Business connector only?  Kindly help

Comment: We are developing an application with AX only. We intend to have it completely free of direct queries to SQL server.

Comment: Would there be a performance gain if you were to do the while loop in an AX X++ class and return a temp  table containin the top X?

Answer (score 1):

In the internal SQL syntax of X++ there is some keywords (`firstOnly, firstOnly10, firstOnly100, firstOnly1000`) to limit how many rows will be fetched. It can be combined with **RecId** field to manually fetch groups of rows simulating pagination:

```
select firstonly10 inventTable // only fetch 10 rows
    index hint ItemIdx
    where inventTable.RecId > lastRecIdFetched // save last recId for each page
       && inventTable.itemId == itemId;
```

You have complete syntax reference of select statement on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa656402.aspx

Comment: The idea is nice, but you have to be sorting by RecId (not ItemId) and the second condition (`inventTable.itemId == itemId`) is a bit weird as it won't ever return more than 1 record.

Comment: You're right, I did copy&paste some code to illustrate my arguments. There are obvious limitations on my description but you get the idea, you can't achieve pagination without some creative aproach. There is not an out-of-the-box solution to do that, as standard forms on the AX client work fine reading all records on the tables (through an internal cache system).